# Test which circles of a set intersect

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have the following problem:
For a set of circles defined by x,y (and maybe z), and a variable radius, r, I want to know which circles intersect with at least 1 other.
Can this problem be solved without testing every pair of circles? (Which means, for a set of 100 circles, 4950 tests must be performed.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without a [mcve] and existing code you're struggling with, this is more of a maths question than a programming one...

Comment: To filter out impossible intersections, you can try to build some spatial data structure like R-tree for bounding squares and check circle intersection only when corresponding rect does intersect with another ones

Comment: You can sort the circles by the distance between them.

Comment: @Daniel That means calculating the distance between each pair of circles, right? Which is what the OP wants to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

**Can this problem be solved without testing every pair of circles?**

Yes. To see why, simplify the problem down to just 1D, so forget 'y' and 'z'. Consider three circles along the line of x in order of increasing index, C1, C2, and C3. If C1 doesn't intersect C2, then it can't intersect C3. Extending this to 'y' isn't too bad.

.......|----C1----|.....|--C2--|...........|---C3---|......

Comment: This assumes that all of the circles have the same radius. If `C3` has a large enough radius, it can intersect both `C1` and `C2`.

Comment: This approach will still work, you just have to remember to scan *backwards* for each circle as well as forward.